# Why is Log4js logger not properly storing files to S3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

It appears that while Log4js is successfully logging data locally within a Node.js environment, there's a specific challenge in configuring it to store log files into an S3 bucket. This discrepancy between local logging and S3 storage suggests potential issues with the S3 appender configuration or AWS credentials setup.

I attempted to configure Log4js to save log files directly to an S3 bucket. My expectation was that once configured correctly, Log4js would seamlessly store the log files in the specified S3 bucket location. However, despite setting up the S3 appender and providing the necessary AWS credentials, the logs aren't being stored in the S3 bucket as expected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.